# How can I export all variable information at a breakpoint in idea IDE for java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, reflection, breakpoints

I want to export every objects' field including nested fields at a breakpoint for comparison.

Now what I need to do is to click and expand all objects that have more fields. After that, I am finally able to ctrl-A and ctrl-C, i.e., copying everything. Therefore, my question is: is there a way to help export that information more quickly?

Attached is the debugger view in IDE.

[image: idea debugging view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bind "Fully expand tree node" action to a shortcut under **Settings > Keymap**:
   [image: IntelliJ IDEA keymap]
2. Focus the debugger "Variables" window, select all variables (Ctrl +A) and invoke the action from step 1 (Fully expand tree node) via the configured shortcut
3. Right-click and choose **View text**
   [image: View text debugger IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: However, I want to get all fields. In your case, I want to get "a" and "b"'s fields. You can click and expand them. In my case, there are so many things to expand. I do not expect to expand them all manually.

Comment: There is "expand all" action, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-216945#focus=Comments-27-4959442.0-0

Comment: I edited the answer. Please mark it as approved if it fits your case.